# CONSEGUIR "UID" EN JSON (PHP)

Tags: php, json

[image]

Hola amigos, necesito de sus conocimientos para poder solucionar este pequeño inconveniente, deseo conseguir la UID que esta dentro de IMAGES / RESULTS / de la matriz /i/models... 
Tengo un código que estoy usando, espero de todo corazón me ayuden.

```
$url = 'https://pastebin.com/raw/1nfChmU1'; 
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($data, true);
foreach ($json['/i/models/'.$id_file.'/textures?optimized=1']['results']as $file_data) {
     foreach($file_data['images'] as $clave1 => $valor1) {
             foreach($clave1 => $valor1['uid'] as $clave2 => $valor2) {
             print "$clave2 => $valor2\n";
             }
```

Si tienen otro código o método, estaría muy agradecidos con ustedes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero que deseo señalar es que si vas a trabajar con un JSON no hay necesidad de convertirlo a array.

En el siguiente código vamos:

- a crear un objeto JSON como tal, con los datos recibidos de la API
- a buscar el objeto que está en `/i/models/c4637851c1e541939c82454cd86d95ed/textures?optimized=1'`. Dado que tiene ciertos caracteres que podrían dar problemas, vamos a usar `{}` para acceder al objeto
- al mismo tiempo, desde el inicio del `for` indicaremos que solamente queremos iterar sobre la propiedad `results` de nuestro JSON, porque es allí donde se encuentran las imágenes
- finalmente, dado que se trata de un array de imágenes, abriremos otro `for` interior para encontrar la propiedad `uid` que es la que te interesa.

El código sería este:

```
$json=json_decode($data); //no ponemos true para que lo deje como JSON
foreach ($json->{'/i/models/c4637851c1e541939c82454cd86d95ed/textures?optimized=1'}->results as $item){
    foreach ($item->images as $image){
        echo $image->uid.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Salida:**

```
ff52d624d38a443e8fbb0555cf72260f
8a9b24bb4c20469e9c4279880062ce17
6c7619c56c8443a78810bd0b9b1e6654
c4cc6483000f4cef9e7c79c03a09e4e6
237f86f4042f4178b8264a2b9232c017
2351f0bbe296402e947c8af6a5758485
53d90bd9aae34f9a84b06098abf9b8e6
f1d12f08d90a4399b956ca020cbd66c0
bd0922768dba479b82dc16467f9ec6db
10f4759bec30453297f0b87621c62cc1
32e4e1c9eb984442b1b7903fe2e0c206
d46df2b389684e3caa1c537d9b3dcc48
791b9c2c7e654a0986312557245a68e3
cdb1bbf4423a4fa4a05f2ee0b66dea57
4557e62705b3469481ffef322ebc0d90
3d81541f862440098bb9f6992dc883ba
c67933dc1e7e4fcbb9ef3254c31809d0
a358de1d25d6468fbbb56603bb28ae75
e2b36f976e624c91980b9b888325530c
22a76cbeee3047f9a06c79ea219dbf03
ef192c1d6b7f4cafa7c47f11b3a3cdb4
0865ae379bbf444d93330a3056b03f06
f98f01b4ea0743aaa71f8e965ec75efc
fceb196f517e4861b0a4ff4d7327ebc2
919cee83c0604d2e96f17b5f2aefcb04
6094b93f8d224dd3beba2a63cfbf0bbd
8c3e5413dba444b8a01d40a3e60e7211
e594a6af2a2a4eefa12086b77773e6ac
```

---

**NOTA:**

Aquí he tomado el JSON  que genera la URL de tu código y esos son los datos que hay en el array de imágenes.